# Can I find out what implementation of ruby is being used?

Tags: ruby, implementation

as questions states is there a way to find out if my ruby implementation is mri, yarv, or jruby, etc.

I want to know how I can check if some errors were due to implementations.

Edited::

I want to check if mine is Rubinus, MRI, YARV, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the **`RUBY_ENGINE`** constant:

On **RMI**:

```
RUBY_ENGINE # => "ruby"
```

On **JRuby**:

```
RUBY_ENGINE # => "jruby"
```

On **Rubinius**:

```
RUBY_ENGINE # => "rbx"
```

**`RUBY_DESCRIPTION`** gives you even more information:

(JRuby)

```
RUBY_DESCRIPTION
# => jruby 1.7.15 (1.9.3p392) 2014-09-03 82b5cc3 on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_11-b12 +jit [darwin-x86_64]
```

Comment: on my cygwin, im getting emtpy
$ echo $RUBY_ENGINE

Comment: Shouldn't RMI be MRI?